# Excel VBA - Formatting partial string in a cell using the length of a string in a different cell

Tags: vba, excel, format, string-formatting

I'm trying to automate a the formatting of a spreadsheet, and I'm stuck on formatting part of a string in a cell. What I need to do is change the colour of part of a string (starting at the beginning of the string) based on the length of the cell next to it.

I think I've figured out part of the solution but I'm not sure on one bit:

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("C4").Select
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=??).font
.Color = -16776961
End With
End Sub
```

I want the ?? to be the length of the cell next to it (in this case D4)

I haven't been using VBA for long, so I'm not even sure I'm on the right track.

If it makes any difference, I would like to be able to apply the formatting to a range of cells (something like C4:C30), but that is beyond me at the moment.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try using `Length:=Len(ActiveCell.Offset(0,1))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can iterate over Range("C4:C30") and change the character formatting based on the text length in Range("D4:D30").

```
Sub Example()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim length As Integer

    For Each r In Range("C4:C30")
        length = Len(r.Offset(0, 1))

        With r.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=length).Font
            .Color = -16776961
        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to call it length, `length:=length` looks like it would cause a reserved name problem

Comment: Length:= is a named parameter not a reserved word.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help!